# $n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge n>0 \iff \exists r \in \mathbb{N},n=r+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I found that this theorem is used many times, but I'm not sure if my below proof is correct or not. Of course, we can only use Peano's axioms and the definitions of addition and order $>$. I feel that any proof for this theorem will be short. I'm very happy to see other proofs for this theorem.

Theorem:

> $n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge n>0 \iff \exists r \in \mathbb{N},n=r+1$

Proof:

> 1. $n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge n>0 \implies \exists r \in \mathbb{N},n=r+1$
>
> It is true that $1>0$ and $1=0+1$. Thus the theorem is true for $n=1$.
>
> Assume the theorem is true for $n=k$.
>
> $k+1=(k)+1 \implies$ The theorem is true for $n=k+1$
>
> By principle of induction, the theorem is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> 2. $n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge n>0 \Leftarrow \exists r \in \mathbb{N},n=r+1$
>
> $\exists r \in \mathbb{N},n=r+1 \implies \exists r \in \mathbb{N} (n=(r+1)+0) \wedge (n \neq 0) \implies n\geq 0 \wedge n \neq 0 \implies n >0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct; the proof is by induction and relies on [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic).

We can simplify it a little bit expressing the theorem as follows:

> $n \ne 0 \to \exists r \ (n=r+1)$.

*Basis* : $n=0$ is straightforward using the [Ex falso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation) tautology: $P \to (\lnot P \to Q)$.

*Induction step* : the induction hypothesis is not really necessary.

Consider $n+1$; by axiom : $\forall x \ \lnot (0=x+1)$ we have that $n+1 \ne 0$ and by [equality axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Logical_formulations) we have : $n+1=n+1$ and thus, by [existential introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization) : $\exists r \ (n+1=r+1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Since $(P \implies Q)$ is false only when ($P$ is true $\wedge$ $Q$ is false). So If $P$ is false (in this case $n=0$), then $(P \implies Q)$ is still true. Am I correct?

Comment: @DungLe - Correct: it is the same as: $\lnot P \to (P \to Q)$. Thus, with $n \ne 0$ as $P$ and $∃r \ (n=r+1)$ as $Q$ we have the follwing instance of the tautology: $(n=0) \to ((n \ne 0) \to ∃r \ (n=r+1))$.

Comment: I think a course of logic is essential for me :)

Comment: @DungLe - if you are interested in a "full developement" of arithmetic (up to division and unicity of quotient and reminder) in a formal way from Peano axioms (and f-o logic with equality) alone, some "old" textbooks are still useful: [Mendelson's Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA153) and [Kleene's Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ).